# Different deployment configurations using Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to have a slightly different deployment configuration in different invironments. That is, in Prod and Ver, I don't want all containers to be deployed.

With docker-compose we solve that by having incremental docker-compose files that we combine, like: `docker-compose up -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-prod.yml`

How can that be done using Helm charts?
We have a structure with Chart.yaml and values.yaml in the top, and then one yaml file per container in a subfolder. The naive solution would be to copy that structure and leave out some of the chart files, but I would prefer to have only one file (at most one file!) per service.

We deploy to AKS using CircleCI.

To summarize: 
Today, each service has it's own yaml file, and on every deploy, all of them gets deployed. I want to configure my charts so that only a subset of the services gets deployed in certain environments.

EDIT:

kubectl has the the possibility to use selectors, like `kubectl create cfg.yaml --selector=tier=frontend` or `kubectl create cfg.yaml --selector=environment=prod` and I already tag my containers, so that would have been simple. But `helm install` does not have the possibility to accept a similar flag and pass it to kubectl.

Answer (score 4):

just create one values file for each environment and target those:

```
helm install . -f values.production.yaml
helm install . -f values.development.yaml
```

you can use condition to toggle deployments, imagine you have something,yaml which you want conditionally deployed:

```
{{ if .Values.something}}
something.yaml original content goes here
{{ end }}
```

Comment: But how can the values toggle deployment of an entire container or not?

Comment: check updated answer, since this is technically a new question

Comment: So I put the entire contents of something,yaml inside the if-statement...? Or do I leave out any tags, like apiVersion and kind?

Comment: everything goes inside, just take existing yaml file and add condition to the top and `{{ end }}` at the bottom

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to list what services should be included, and then just parameterize that list. But I find it difficult to find info on how the different tags are interpreted. A lot of documentation on how to string-manipulate them, but what does "kind" mean? "nodeSelector"? etc.
Sorry, just blowing off some frustrated steam here.

Comment: this has nothing to do with helm :) but I dont like helm as well, tbh